# Displaying an image in the header of a PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, cakephp, tcpdf

I have successfully generated PDFs with images in the body using the normal html `<img>` tag. But I cannot get images to display in the header.

The class has been extended and I overwrite the Header method with

```
public function Header() {
    // Header and footer images
    $image_header = 'files/pdf_images/header.jpg'; // also tried "app/webroot/files/pdf_images/header.jpg"
    $this->Image($image_header, 67,10, 76, '', 'JPG', '', 'C', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);   
}
```

But no success.
I think it's because I am misunderstanding where the path is relative to. I am using CakePHP (2.6.7) and so the this class is in `www/root/vendors/HtmlToPdf/HtmlToPdf.php` and the image is in `www/root/app/webroot/files/pdf_images/header.jpg`.

In the main body of html paths such as `files/pdf_images/header.jpg` are fine (I think it retrieves them in the same manner as a request to the server would).

Comment: Try this  $this->Html->image("img.png", array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'name', 'action' => 'name')
);

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that doesn't work here - the class that `$this` refers to is the extended TCPDF one - not any part of CakePHP. This is a separate library that I am using in conjunction with Cake on this particular project but on another project Cake would not be there necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I had forgotten to remove the lines

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
```

For anyone else trying to use TCPDF with CakePHP - the paths to images are relative to the webroot - so in my case it was `files/pdf_images/header.jpg`

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer so the question is "answered" thanks!

Comment: I will do but I can only accept my own answer in 2 days time ;)